# Android - Stop PhoneStateListener / BR / UnregisterReceiver

Tags: android

I have a problem to stop a PhoneStateListener. I tried to use unregisterReceiver() but it didn't work. I did read the site and saw that I have to use LISTEN.NON but I am unable to do it.

My questions are the following : 
1 - where do I have to put my "telephony.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);" in my code ?
2 - do I have to use unregisterReceiver ?

My code is not easy to explain and quite long so I won't give all my code but just the main view.

**In fact : I start a service from timer. This service register a BR**

/* First one */

```
public class TmrSettingsCheck extends BroadcastReceiver
 {
  public void setTimer(long milli)
   { // setRepeating } 

  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)         
   {
    // Try to know if we have to start or stop the service
    context.startService(new Intent(context, SvcCall.class));  
    OR
    context.stopService(new Intent(context, SvcCall.class));
   }
 }
```

/* Second one */

```
public class SvcCall extends Service
 {
  private BroadcastReceiver br_call;

  public void onCreate()
   { // Creation }

  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
   {  
    // register the broadcast receiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(ACTION_OUT);
    filter.addAction(ACTION_IN);
    this.br_call = new CallBR(this._context);
    this.registerReceiver(this.br_call, filter);
    return (START_STICKY);
   }

  public class CallBR extends ClsCallReceiver
   {
    public CallBR(Context context)  
     { // constructor }

    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(String number, Date start) 
     { // XYZ
     }

    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(String number, Date start, Date end) 
     { // XYZ }

    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(String number, Date start) 
     { // XYZ }

    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(String number, Date start, Date end) 
     { // XYZ }

    protected void onMissedCall(String number, Date start) 
     { // XYZ }
   }

  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
   { return null; }

  public void onDestroy()
  {
   this.unregisterReceiver(this.br_call);          
   super.onDestroy();
   } 
 }
```

/* Third one */

```
public abstract class ClsCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
 {
  public static PhonecallStartEndDetector listener;
  String outgoingSavedNumber;
  protected Context savedContext;
  TelephonyManager telephony;

  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
   {
    savedContext = context;
    if (listener == null)
     listener = new PhonecallStartEndDetector();

    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) 
     {
      listener.setOutgoingNumber(intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER"));
      return;
     }
    this.telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
    this.telephony.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
   }

  public class PhonecallStartEndDetector extends PhoneStateListener 
   {
    public PhonecallStartEndDetector() 
     { // XYZ }

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
     { // XYZ }    
   }

  protected abstract void onIncomingCallStarted(String number, Date start);
  protected abstract void onOutgoingCallStarted(String number, Date start);
  protected abstract void onIncomingCallEnded(String number, Date start, Date end); 
  protected abstract void onOutgoingCallEnded(String number, Date start, Date end);
  protected abstract void onMissedCall(String number, Date start);   
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure of your specific problem, but I heard that you should use a try catch for unregisterreciever because if the reciever isn't registered your app will crash unregistering a reciever that isn't registered

Comment: @JRowan : I already tried with a try/finally block. Still the same result : the PhoneStateListener is still listening. I found that I have to use PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE but I can't find a way to it (relative to my previous code/post).

Comment: You have multiple broadcast recievers running, maybe you have to instantiate them a certain way uniquely register and unregister, maybe just registering general broadcastreciever is starting all broadcastrecievers and gets lost unregistering, I only ever used 1 broadcast reciever for proximityalerts, sorry if im wasting your time,idk

Comment: Actually I am not in any of these cases, I mean I register/unregister the good way, I think. I unregistered other BR this way and it worked but in this case i use PhoneStateListener and I know it won't work if I don't use "PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE". If anyone can tell me how to do that ... (thanks JRowan).

Answer (score 4):

Use LISTEN_NONE as parameter to listen method to stop listening for updates. this will make the listener listen to none.

```
telephonymanager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE );
```